# Is there a function/WinAPI to tell if one string starts with another string in a case-insensitive linguistic way?

Tags: c++, winapi, c-strings, crt, linguistics

The best way to illustrate my question is with this example (that doesn't work if I use the [`strstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strstr-wcsstr-mbsstr-mbsstr-l?view=vs-2017) CRT function):

```
const wchar_t* s1 = L"Hauptstraße ist die längste";
const wchar_t* s2 = L"Hauptstrasse";

bool b_s1_starts_with_s2 = !!wcsstr(s1, s2);
_ASSERT(b_s1_starts_with_s2);   //Should be true
```

So far the only WinAPI that seems to recognize linguistic string equivalency is [`CompareStringEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-comparestringex) when used with the `LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE` flag, but it is somewhat tricky & inefficient to use for this purpose as I will have to call it on `s2` repeatedly until I reach its end.

So I was wondering if there's a better approach to doing this (under Windows)?

EDIT: *Here's what I mean:*

```
bool b_s1_starts_with_s2 = false;

int ln1 = (int)wcslen(s1);
int ln2 = (int)wcslen(s2);

for(int p = 1; p <= ln1; p++)
{
    if(::CompareString(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE,
        s1, p,
        s2, ln2) == CSTR_EQUAL)
    {
        //Match
        b_s1_starts_with_s2 = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing; the title says "starts with" but then you refer to `wcsstr` which searches the target string rather than just comparing the prefix.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: OK, sure. What would you chose to use for that? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Just clarify your question - do you mean "starts with" or do you mean "contains"?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: _Is there a function/WinAPI to tell if one string **starts with** another string in a case-insensitive linguistic way?_

Comment: Isn't that what your `CompareString` example does? Just give it the length to compare and it'll compare it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: It works but it's inefficient for a large string `s1`

Comment: I don't understand why. You only need to call it once to compare the prefix.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: because you don't know upfront the length of `s2` string when it's evaluated "linguistically" to a different set of wchars. In my particular example character `ß` has linguistic equivalence to `ss` in German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FindNLSString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winnls/nf-winnls-findnlsstring), check if the return value is zero.

Evidently it matches `ß` with `ss`

```
const wchar_t *s1 = L"Hauptstraße ist die längste";
const wchar_t *s2 = L"Hauptstrasse";

INT found = 0;
int start = FindNLSString(0, LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE, s1, -1, s2, -1, &found);
wprintf(L"start = %d\n", start);

s1 = L"δεθ Testing Greek";
s2 = L"ΔΕΘ";
start = FindNLSString(0, LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE, s1, -1, s2, -1, &found);
wprintf(L"start = %d\n", start);
```

Comment: Hey, I knew there was an API for that :) Thanks for your help! Somehow I missed that one. Slightly adjusting your code, the following call does the trick: `bool b_s1_starts_with_s2 = ::FindNLSStringEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, FIND_STARTSWITH | LINGUISTIC_IGNORECASE, s1, -1, s2, -1, &found, NULL, NULL, NULL) == 0;`

Comment: The one downside is that that API is not available on XP. But tbh I'm not sure if XP supported linguistic differences between characters anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but I think you probably could use [`LCMapStringEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-lcmapstringex) to transform all strings to lowercase appropriately for the locale, and then do a normal string prefix match with `wcsncmp`.

(As noted in comments, it makes no sense that you used `wcsstr` in your example since `wcsstr` determines if one string contains another string.  To determine if one string starts with another string, it's more efficient to use `wcsncmp` with the length of the prefix string.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't seem to have `LCMapString` convert it for both of my example strings. (It'd be nice to use it as a fallback method for XP support.) Otherwise, `FindNLSStringEx` seems to be the API as was suggested in another answer.